# Trying to Zoom (in Accessibility) the iPad Sidecar display gives -501 misc error

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, accessibility, zoom, sidecar

As per the title. My mac is 10.15.7 while my iPad is 13.5.1.

Details: First set up sidecar.

Then, go to System Preferences - Accessibility - Zoom - Choose Display - Choose sidecar display.

Then, error happens. I haven't seen this elsewhere. Any insights welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Is the error on the Mac or on the iPad?  You shouldn't have to but, have you tried resetting the iPad?  Make sure you back everything up first.

Comment: The mac throws the error, and it immediately disconnects the sidecar connection. Sorry for not mentioning this. I would prefer to try less drastic measures first, but thank you for responding